# How to limit file permissions of a program

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am a student that wants to design an online judge system.

I have a problem: In order to keep the server safe, I must make the program not have rights to read or write any files
The program is what another user submits through the online judge system. It isn't the sever program itself.

The users of the online judge system submit their source code, then the server program compiles and runs it. So the server program must keep the server safe.

My platform is Windows, I use C++ for my programming.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want your program to be in C++@Windows ?

Comment: I think it would be a valid question, if the language that your online judge wants to support is C++.

Comment: Run your program as a user that has no permissions on the host (akin to `nobody` on a *nix box).

Comment: I want to know if there is any way to ban file functions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily prevent what a program itself does and it is not possible to verify that the program is non-malevolent.

What you can do: Run the program as a user with limited (close to non) access-rights. Your server program needs to become that user and execute the program it has compiled. You possibly want to also use that user-account to actually compile the program (in the unlikely case someone knows how to exploit your compiler).

The windows command to execute a program as a different user is: `runas`.

Comment: My idea is using CreateProcessAsUser to run the user's program with a non-group user. But this way still cannot limit the program writing or reading file. Can you tell me some specified ways?

Comment: @user1518008 How does this not limit reading or writing files? If the user that runs the program has no read or write access to a file or directory, how can he read or write a file?

Comment: That's my problem. If the server program traverse every directories and files to change the permissions to this non-group user. The efficiency may be low?

Comment: @user1518008 Why would you need to do that? Can't you create a group that owns nothing and make that user part of that group?

Comment: the user doesn't belong to any groups.

Comment: @snow I don't understand what you are asking. You might want to open a new question.

Comment: @snow This is a Windows question. I have no idea why you think a comment about what or what would not work on Linux is applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions of files and directories, and then use CreateProcessAsUser to run the programs submitted by users as a user with limited (close to non) access-rights.

Comment: How to change all the permissions of files and directories?