# Changing the permission of a program in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, permissions

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434752/how-to-limit-file-permissions-of-a-program), but i didn't get my answer.

I am trying to design a judge.

> The users of the online judge system submit their source code, then
>   the server program compiles and runs it. So the server program must
>   keep the server safe.

And there are a lot of things a user can use to make changes to the server.

How can i change the permission of a program? So that compiled code won't be able to do anything except printing something!

P.S: searching for suspicioius words is not a good idea. For instance, The user can use the following command instead of word `system` in C++:

```
#define glue(a,b) a ## b
glue(sys,tem) ("rm *");  //DO NOT RUN THIS CODE
```

So actually user used the following code without using the word `system`:

```
system ("rm *"); //DO NOT RUN THIS CODE
```

Comment: run them on VM-es or containers created on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run them in a `chroot` jail, with user id set to nobody or some nonce account if nobody actually can do something significant.  (You can use `su` or `sudo` for this.)  Or even in their own VM.  Pipe the output into a file, and read it from your judge program.

Answer (score 2):

The are two options for you: the one you are currently looking into - trying to make your compiler, aka the server process that runs the user provided source code detect "exploits". And that might be **hard**. If you allow users to send you c++ source code, there is **a lot** of things that become possible. I guess you would need some real c++ gurus in order to get that solution even "half way secure".

So, option two: you have to run that user-provided input within some sort of sandbox. Examples could be:

1. A docker container (but for sure: a non-privileged container; run by a user, not root)
2. A virtual machine

If you are serious about what you are doing, you would probably focus on option 2 first (because that gives you a lot of benefit, at medium cost); but you definitely want to look into option 1, too (because one could learn from that **a lot**).